# Get Vaadin Version in flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 8, I was able to retrieve version information with

```
com.vaadin.shared.Version.getFullVersion()
```

In Vaadin Flow I cannot find a way to get the current version, at least not the one that I expected. I have found this one

```
com.vaadin.flow.server.Version.getFullVersion()
```

but the return value is `1.2.2` and not the expected `12.0.0`. I guess it is the server version or something..

**How do I get the used version of vaadin framework correctly in vaadin flow?**

Comment: Did you try getMajorVersion() instead of FullVersion...the api has different methods for it: https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/server/Version.html#getFullVersion--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from 10, a Vaadin version doesn't have any content of its own, not even a version number marker. It's only a set of dependency versions that have been tested to work well together.

`com.vaadin.flow.server.Version.getFullVersion()` gives the version of the Vaadin Flow dependency. This is in most cases a more relevant version number to look at for technical purposes.

Vaadin 10 and Vaadin 11 used Flow 1.0.x, whereas Vaadin 12 uses version 1.2.x. Vaadin 13 will most likely use Flow version 1.3.x or 2.0.x, depending on how big changes will be included by then.

Comment: Vaadin 13 uses flow 1.4.x and Vaadin 14 will most likely use Flow version 1.5.x or 2.0.x, depending on how big changes will be included by then

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach to get the Vaadin version is to use

```java
VaadinCoreShrinkWrap.class.getAnnotation(NpmPackage.class).version()
```

Not optimal, but it should work.

This approach works starting from Vaadin 14. It will cause errors with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Vaadin version and not Flow version I see one option to make it happen but it requires more code and some maven configuration.

You should

- Create a properties file including the line `vaadin.version=${vaadin.version}`
- Make sure the file is included in resources that maven-resources-plugin filter with something like the following in you build config:

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/config.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/config.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

- Read properties file and get value for version property

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(MainView.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
properties.get("vaadin.version");
```

Comment: Where do you put the `<resources>...</resources>` in the POM?  Also, when you say `vaadin.version=${vaadin.version}`, do you mean `${vaadin.version}` literally, or do you mean we need to hard code it into the properties file itself? So can we leave it as `vaadin.version=${vaadin.version}`, or do we need to replace it with `vaadin.version=13.0.9` ( assuming my vaadin version is 13.0.9, of course )?

Comment: You add it to the `build` tag so that it's considered by the maven-resources-plugin.
This will include the properties file in the filtered files, and for the filtered files the `${vaadin.version}` will be replaced by the value of your `vaadin.version` property defined in your pom.
Similar use case, but for `project.version` is done in [this demo project](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/demo/pom.xml#L69-L85)